# 検証用ステージングアプリの Google Developer Console 上での扱いについて

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Androidアプリの運用者です。
以下の同内容の2つのアプリ (公開用アプリと、検証用アプリ) を Google Play Console へ登録しています。

・アプリA：製品版アプリ (ストアへは公開中)
・アプリB：ステージング環境データベースに接続した、Aと同内容の社内検証用のアプリ (ストアへは非公開中)

上記について 3点、質問させてください。

①
アプリBは Google Play ポリシーの適用対象となりますでしょうか？
ポリシーのアップデートの際に、対応が必要でしょうか？

②
アプリBは、アプリAと同内容のアプリであることから、下記のポリシー違反 (なりすまし) に該当しますでしょうか？
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374?hl=ja&ref_topic=9969539

③
①のメンテナンスコストと、②のリスクが存在する場合、アプリをPlay Consoleから削除リクエストをしたほうがよいのではないかと考えていますが、一般的には、アプリBのような検証用のステージングアプリは、どのように扱うのが正しいでしょうか？

ご見解いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。